# find filenames with non latin characters in their names

Tags: regex, find, language, freebsd

I want to find files with foreign filenames in them, I'm using a regex to find such files with another tool but I don't know how to use them in find.

The system is FreeBSD so the find command is a bit different from gnu find. Also these filenames could also include latin characters so excluding latin alphabet [^A-Za-z] wouldn't work.

Here is what I use for that tool ( everything is in a file ):

```
*\[DE\]* #....[DE]...
*\[JP\]* #....[JP]...
*\[RU\]* #....[RU]...
*\[FR\]* #....[FR]...
*\[KR\]* #....[KR]...
*\[PL\]* #....[PL]...
*\[AU\]* #....[AU]...
*\[IT\]* #....[IT]...
*[\p{Han}]*      #....{Kanji}...
*[\p{Hiragana}]* #....{Hiragana}...
*[\p{Katakana}]* #....{Katakana}...
*[\p{Cyrillic}]* #....{Cyrillic ( Russian etc)}...
*[\p{Hangul}]*   #....{Hangul ( Korean )}...
*German*    #....German...
*Japanese*  #....Japanese...
*Korean*    #....Korean...
*Spanish*   #....Spanish...
*Italian*   #....Italian...
*Polish*    #....Polish...
*French*    #....French...
```

Is there a way to find all files including these?

Comment: Yes, use the tool you're already using. You won't be able to use them with find as they're non standard abbreviations for any number of things. What's the name of the other tool you're using? Does it include information about its specifics in its documentation. Something like `*German*` will not work, unless the document name just include "SomethingGermanSomething".

Comment: Why wouldn't `[^A-Za-z] ` work? It should match any filenames with at least one non basic character. You would need to wildcard the front and back, e.g. `.*[^A-Za-z].*`

Comment: @RichardSmith Because as I said the files also include latin alphabet characters.

Comment: @Seth The regex is not standard, it's for that tool, but that's for another purpose. It doesn't list them.

Comment: Does that mean you expect something like Donaudampfschiffahrtsgesellschaft to show up even if it's just regular Latin characters? Otherwise reporting every file that has at least one non Latin character should work pretty well? Which is what @RichardSmith suggests if I understand correctly.

Comment: I did try that, and it doesn't work. This is the command I used: `find . -regex '.*[^A-Za-z0-9].*'` It shows both hiragana/katakana named, and english named files.

Comment: Ok, I think the problem is in FreeBSD's `find` command.. I installed `fd-find` via package manager and it solved my problem. The command I used `fd '.*[\p{Han}\p{Katakana}\p{Hiragana}\p{Hangul}\p{Cyrillic}].*' -x rm {} \;`. This worked perfectly.